# Enabling spellcheck in the Ace editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I've embedded the Ace Editor (using vim mode) and I'm trying to get the spellcheck extension to work. I'm loading `ext-spellcheck.js` right after loading `ace.js` and I have the following 2 lines as part of my configuration:

```
ace.require("ace/ext/spellcheck");
...
editor.setOptions({
  ...
  spellcheck: true,
  ...
});
```

However, I don't see any difference when typing misspelled words. What am I missing?

Comment: Any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ace does not support spellchecking.

Comment: The strange thing is that there seems to be an extension `ext-spellcheck.js` included in the repository. Does that have a different purpose?